# Why onClick event not work on dojo MenuItem?

Tags: dojo, onclick, menuitem

I'm studying Dojo 1.10.4, my problem is that the onClick event does not work on **dijit/MenuItem**. I tried it on other item widgets like **dijit/CheckedMenuItem** and **dijit/RadioMenuItem**, none of their click events work, and the API docs didn't give any tips about it.

At last, I found it only works if it's contained in **dijit/MenuBar**. Should Item widgets be contained in **dijit/MenuBar** or **dijit/Menu**? How are the events processed on dojo widgets?

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async:true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script>
  require(["dojo/parser"],function(parser){
    parser.parse();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar" >
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" onclick="alert();">it works</div>
</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" onclick="alert();">it     doesn't work</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include a code example of what isn't working... right now it seems to me that you're trying to create a MenuItem without having a Menu, I'm not seeing the logic behind this, but a code example might explain. Anyways, a Menuitem should be used within a Menu component (could be a dropdownmenu as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case MenuItem needs a ContainerWidget like Menu or MenuBar. You add the Item as a child like :

```
require([
         "dojo/dom",
         "dijit/MenuItem",
         "dijit/DropDownMenu",
         "dijit/form/DropDownButton"
         ],
         function(dom,MenuItem,DropDownMenu,DropDownButton){
           var myMenu = new DropDownMenu();


          var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({
                            id:"M1",
                            label:"Show M1",
                            onClick:function(){
                             //do what you want to do here
                             }
                            });
           myMenu.addChild(menuItem1);
           });
```

Studying this might help you too to understand how it works.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/DropDownMenu.html#dijit-dropdownmenu

Regards